# printf function on multi thread program

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm writing a simple program in c, the program has two threads and two global's var, but the printf function not working, I know that `printf` is not thread safe and also if I will add `\n` in the print it will work, but I want to understand why it's not working without that?
I'm adding the code,

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int i;
int j;

void* runi(void* _temp)
{
    while(1)
    {
        i++;
        if(i==1000)
        {
            printf("i: %d",i);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void* runj(void* _temp)
{
    while(1)
    {
        j++;
        if(j==1000)
        {
            printf("j: %d",j);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
main ()
{
    pthread_t threadI,threadJ;
    pthread_create(&threadI,NULL,runi,NULL);
    pthread_create(&threadJ,NULL,runj,NULL);
    pthread_join(threadI,NULL);
    pthread_join(threadJ,NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you'll have to be more specific.  "it's not working" is not very helpful for debugging.

Comment: When I wort that it doesn't work i mean that the printf doesn't print, i know that i can use flush but I want to understand why it's not printing.

Comment: It doesn't print because stdout is buffered.

Comment: I know that the buffer it what makes the function not to work but way?? why it's not printing garbage or wrong data, why its not printing at all

Comment: You would have been exposed the same problem had you eliminated code, including the threads, the functions, and used a single endless loop with a one-shot `printf` like what you have, with no trailing newline. as has been stated once here, and once in Basile's answers, Your code works, just not as you expected.

Comment: Output appears when you print a newline, or when the internal buffer is full. You don't print any newlines at all; you've no idea when the data will appear.  Each call to `printf()` is thread-safe -- the function must behave as if it locks `stdout` with `flockfile()` on entry and unlocks it with `funlockfile()` on exit. While it has the file locked, no other thread can use `stdout`. However, the operations of the two threads can be interleaved arbitrarily. Also, since `i` and `j` are not unsigned variables, you have undefined behaviour on overflow. On your system, it probably continues, but...

Comment: Also, any output that remains in the buffer at normal program termination would appear then, but this program never terminates.

Comment: Your threads only print once per 4 billion increments (loop iterations), roughly.  Assuming 1 nanosecond per loop, that means that roughly once every 4 seconds.  Your buffer size might be 4 KiB or 8 KiB (or bigger), and each output is 7 bytes, so it might take 500+ cycles before the buffer is full enough to be flushed, or 2000 seconds, or more than half an hour.  Were you just too impatient?  (You can see how fast the counters appear by adding a newline to the output.  Was I about right, or wildly optimistic?)

Comment: thx @JonathanLeffler it's not that I impatient but its a question that I been asked why this cond well not print the buffer.

Comment: OTOH, when I try an optimized, unthreaded version of the code (GCC 7.2.0), the compiler simply iterates on the `printf()` call, eliminating the increment of `i`.  At least, with an `unsigned` variable for the counter (avoiding UB).  Beware modern optimizers; they're very good.

Comment: @yaodav: You've been told by multiple people why the output doesn't appear when you think it should; the output is buffered -- probably line buffered, but since you don't print any newlines, that's moot.  If you print newlines, the output appears.  You said that.  That shows 'line buffering' at work.  Newlines trigger a flush.  There's nothing anybody can usefully say more.  I suppose you could use `setvbuf()` to make standard output unbuffered.  That'd be your decision to make.  By default, it will be (at least) line buffered, and that's what you're seeing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) is somehow thread safe<sup>*</sup> (see discussion in [unlocked_stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/unlocked_stdio.3.html)..., and consider [flockfile(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/flockfile.3.html)) but stdio is buffered, and you should call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) in your routines.

<sup>(`printf` is perhaps thread safe because two concurrent `printf` might not intermix their output, but nothing is told about flushing buffers)</sup>

So code instead

```
    if(i==1000) {
        printf("i: %d",i);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
```

<sup>(then you'll see some output)</sup>

BTW, I recommend ending most of your `printf` format control strings with a newline `\n`.... You could also add some delay by doing some [nanosleep(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) or [usleep(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html) in your `runi` & `runj` routines.

It is the [buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer) which explains that you are disappointed. And `stdout` should be buffered for efficiency reasons (see [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html)...). Be aware that system calls (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) for Linux) such as [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) are quite expensive operations. On Linux use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand what system calls are done.

If you want to understand the implementation of `printf` on Linux, study the source code of your C standard library - which is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). It probably is GNU [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), but could be something else like [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/), etc.

BTW, your threads are never ending (since `runi`  and `runj` never return), and you `pthread_join` them. That call is blocking indefinitely. Use [ltrace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html) to observe that.

You could also consider adding some `sleep(2); fflush(stdout);` in your `main`  before the first `pthread_join`; you'll then observe some output.

At last, for such experiments,  I recommend some periodic printing. Replace the `i==1000` condition by `i%10000 == 0` ....

You never explicitly flush your `stdout`  so its gets flushed when its buffer (perhaps 8Kbytes) is full, or at end of your `main` (which is *not* reached in your case). [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) cleverly commented that you might need to wait an hour for that (buffer full condition) to happen.

Beware of [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) and of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: tnx, but I know how to make it work but I want to know why the code that I wrote doesn't work.

Comment: Your code "works" but not as you expected. And the reason is the buffering.